# Change textbox text according to text in another textbox

Tags: c#, webforms

I am doing a web form application. In this form, I have three textbox and one of them show the result of the nuktiplication of the other two textbox.Let say three textboxes are txtMulti1, txtMulti2 and txtMultiRst.

This is my code so far, but not working

```
public txtMultiRst_TextChange(       obeject sender, EventArgs e) {
    int result = int.Parse(txtMultRst.Text);
    result = int.Parse(txtMulti1.Text) * int.Parse(txtMulti2.Text);
}
```

The way I was thinking is txtMuli1 * txtMulti2 and the answer should display in txtMulRst. Help will be great thanks

Comment: txtMultiRst.Text = result.ToString();

Answer (score 3):

You should set  `txtMultRst.Text` property.

```
int result =  int.Parse(txtMulti1.Text) * int.Parse(txtMulti2.Text);
txtMultRst.Text = result.ToString();
```

In your case, you are creating new variable `result` and set value to it, not to the `txtMultRst.Text`, because `int` is a value type.

Also, I suggest to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, to handle situation when  `txtMulti1.Text` is not parseble to int.

```
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    if (int.TryParse (txtMulti1.Text, out value1) && int.TryParse (txtMulti2.Text, out value2))
    {
         int result =  value1  * value2; 
         txtMultRst.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Valentin, thanks for your reply. I am wondering should I use the textchange events on txtMultiRst? Or should I use it in the other 2 textbox?

Comment: @DragonBorn well, it depends on buisness logic, but I think the best way is to create button and calculate multiplication on button down event handler.

Comment: I want to show the result to user as they are tying in the text box. Will it be better if I put the TextChange event in my txtMulti2?

Comment: @DragonBorn I've updated answer, so you can create one method for both textboxs textchange event.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is a user-input field I can't recommend [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) strongly enough.  Otherwise the first time they enter something that is not a number it will throw an exception.

Try something like this:

```
int n1, n2;
if(Int32.TryParse(txtMulti1.Text, out n1) && Int32.TryParse(txtMulti2.Text, out n2)
    txtMultRst.Text = (n1*n2).ToString();
else
    txtMultRst.Text = "Please enter valid numbers only";
```